# Rogers' Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

Holder's inequality is quite well known, but what is less well-known is that the form in which most people know it was developed by Frigyes Riesz in 1910, and not by Otto Holder. In addition, Otto Holder didn't actually initially discover the inequality, it was in fact Leonard James Rogers who proved the inequality in 1888. The Cauchy-Schwarz Masterclass by J. Michael Steele looks to prove the form of Holder's that Rogers actually proved; which I will call henceforth Rogers' inequality.
It's the proof of this I'm stuck with

**Rogers' Inequality** For positive real r,s and t with r < s < t, and nonnegative real $a_{k}b_{k}$ with $k = 1,2,...,n,$ we have $$(\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k}b_{k}^{s})^{t-r} \leq (\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}b_{k}^{r})^{t-s}(\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}b_{k}^{t})^{s-r},$$ or equivalently $$(S_{s})^{t-r} \leq (S_{r})^{t-s}(S_{t})^{s-r}$$ where $S_{p} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}b_{k}^{p}$ for positive real p.

**Proof** We prove this with the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means in the form $$ x_{1}^{w_{1}}x_{2}^{w_{2}}...x_{n}^{w_{n}} \leq (\frac{w_{1}x_{1} + w_{2}x_{2} + ... + w_{n}x_{n}}{w_1 + w_2 + ... + w_n})^{w_1 + w_2 + ... + w_n}$$

for arbitrary positive real $w_1,w_2,...,w_n$, and nonnegative $x_1,x_2,...,x_n.$ The substitutions $w_k = a_{k}b_{k}^{s}$ and $x_{k} = b_{k}^{t-s},$ and also $w_k = a_kb_k^s$ and $x_k = b_{k}^{r-s},$ give $$(b_{1}^{a_1b_1^s}b_{2}^{a_2b_2^s}...b_{n}^{a_nb_n^s})^{t-s} \leq (\frac{S_t}{S_s})^{S_s},$$ and $$(b_{1}^{a_1b_1^s}b_{2}^{a_2b_2^s}...b_{n}^{a_nb_n^s})^{r-s} \leq (\frac{S_r}{S_s})^{S_s}.$$ Combining these gives $$(\frac{S_s}{S_r})^{\frac{S_s}{s-r}} \leq b_{1}^{a_1b_1^s}b_{2}^{a_2b_2^s}...b_{n}^{a_nb_n^s} \leq (\frac{S_t}{S_s})^{\frac{S_s}{t-s}},$$

it then says the result follows, but I'm not actually sure how, could someone explain to me why the last result gives Rogers' inequality?

Comment: Just commenting bc I thought this was cool! I use Holders inequality as we know it all the time and never heard of this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the $S_s$th root of both sides (we can assume $S_s> 0$, else the inequality is trivial):
$$\left(\frac{S_s}{S_r}\right)^{1/(s-r)}\le\left(\frac{S_t}{S_s}\right)^{1/(t-s)}$$
Raise both sides to the $(s-r)(t-s)$ power (noting $(s-r)(t-s)>0$):
$$\left(\frac{S_s}{S_r}\right)^{t-s}\le \left(\frac{S_t}{S_s}\right)^{s-r}$$
Multiply both sides by $(S_s)^{s-r}(S_r)^{t-s}$ (noting $(S_s)^{s-r}(S_r)^{t-s}\ge0$):
$$(S_s)^{t-s}(S_s)^{s-r}\le (S_t)^{s-r}(S_r)^{t-s}$$